# Images folder lost after Elastic Bean Stalk restarted. Any way to restore them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had recently faced some issue with the application (Django Application) because of which I had to restart my Elastic Bean Stalk. Once the application has been restarted I lost my data which was residing in the upload folder of the application directory.

I have no idea how to get them back.

Is there any possibility that I can recover them. Any file recovery software can help?

Answer (score 2):

Your upload folder might have been mounted to ephemeral volume which is located on physical EC2 machine. If you want to make data resistant to shut down, use EBS volume instead.

Please find more details here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/customize-ephemeral-and-ebs-volumes-in-elastic-beanstalk-environments/

Comment: Dimitry, Currently my `lsblk` is not showing any Ephemeral Volume attached ? I am not sure how this can get my files which have been lost. Need some more input on this please.